# How to create a package for new gazebo plugins?

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-plugins, packages, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have created plugins for IR Sensor and Sonar Sensor. I want to create a package for both so that it can be tested on other computer and then submitted to ROS. Further i would like to mention here that i have created Sonar Sensor (IRSensor and its controller are already present in gazebo) by the name of SonarSensor and its controller named "sonar_array" as well. I have also done some changes to files called MultiRayShape and gz.h( i have added sonarIface in the gz.h). Similarly xacro files are also created for IRSensor and Sonar Sensor.

I would like to know how to create package for sonar sensor, IRSensor plugin and SonarSensor plugin. Any Help in this regard will be appreciated.

Regards,
Saeed Anwar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11115/how-to-create-a-package-for-new-gazebo-plugins?/) by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2011-09-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you mean you want to create a stack to regroup your different packages?

You can use roscreate-stack and roscreate-pkg to create a stack or a package ( [see this wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscreate) )

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-09-05**:
these are only source files like the one present in /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_plugins (gazebo_ros_ir.cpp) and the xacro files present /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/pr2_common/pr2_description/urdf/sensors (xx.gazebo.xacro and xx.urdf.xacro)

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-09-04**:
Are those binaries or sources?

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-09-04**:
I have two kind of files. some files are newly created (GazeboRosIr, and GazeboRosSonar, Sonarsensor, sonar_array) and some are modified files (MultiRayShape, gz). now how can i deal with all these

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-09-04**:
If you depend on roscpp for example, you'll have a src and an include directory where you can put your sources. If your work contains files that should be copied to the gazebo package, may be you should propose a patch for this package?

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-09-04**:
Thank for your Reply. For time being i am only creating packages, not regrouping. I have seen this tutorial, but i does specify how to put files in the package. further how i will specify the path for the files to be put in the gazebo during package creation?